# Android 4.4: Package is unknown in adb shell

Tags: android, adb

I have been reading about this issue but I'm not able to solve it yet. When I enter in `adb shell` in Android 4.4 devices and execute `run-as my.app.package`, I get this error:

> Package 'my.app.package' is unknown

App is installed in debuggable mode. In previous Android versions there is no problem with that.

Can anybody helps me?

Comment: the package needs to be `debuggable` to be used with `run-as`

Comment: It is: `App is installed in debuggable mode`